# Проблема с bash-средой

Tags: ubuntu, bash, sh

Здравствуйте! Не могу решить проблему следующего характера 
При запуске простейшего sh-скрипта выдает синтаксическую ошибку. Система `Ubuntu 14.04.`
сам скрипт:

```
#!/bin/bash
one () {
echo 'One'
}
one
```

Запускаю командой: `bash ./script.sh`

вывод консоли:

```
/home/techexpertbase/shscripts/textlogger.sh: строка 2: ошибка синтаксиса около неожиданной лексемы `$'{\r''
'home/techexpertbase/shscripts/textlogger.sh: строка 2: `one () {
```

Перерыл кучу интернетов, ничего не помогло. Алиасы не трогал, bashrc не трогал, сравнил его на чистой системе - одинаковы.

Comment: окончания строк в файле смени на UNIX'овые..

Comment: Да ну.....спасибо вам большое! На эту мелочь я не обращал внимания вообще!

Comment: @Fat-Zer, так как эта проблема встречается каждый раз при написании bash-скриптов в Windows-редакторе, думаю, вам стоит оформить полноценный ответ про окончания строк.

Comment: @Arhad, не соберусь я всё же написать полноценный ответ... но ни кого не останавливаю от этого....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конвертировать скрипт в Unix-style можно программой dos2unix:

```
dos2unix /path_to_script
```